# unittest mock not mocking

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

Just picking up python

```
def test_load( self ):
    with patch( 'base.data.load.loadEngine.libLoad.extractDBData', autospec=True, return_value=None):
    #libLoad.extractDBData = MagicMock( return_value=[ {'x':'value1'} ] )
        self.assertEqual(
            load(loadName='MyLoadName', configName='PROD', sqlName='sampleSQL', loginName='loginName', password='password'),
            [{'x': 'value'}] )
```

Within my code, load calls another module base.data.load.loadEngine.libLoad.extractDBData, the method I wanted to replace. In my case though, the patch is not happening.

Comment: It is actually execution the method base.data.load.loadEngine.libLoad.extractDBData

Comment: I think we need more information to track this down... e.g. what does the function `load` look like and how was `extractDBData` imported in `load`'s namespace?

Comment: in load, the import is like this: -------- from base.data.load.loadEngine import libLoad as fl.....and further down.... .fl.extractDBData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to patch the relative path to the method:

`with patch('path.to.your.pythonfile.fl.extractDBData', autospec=True, return_value=None):
    ...`